# State changes but doesn't call render function of parent component

Tags: reactjs

# Its is my parent component i have dispatch the action from child component and state changes but render function of parent component does not called .

In child component every time when i click on checkbox then i dispatch the action for updating the state in reducer and i received new state in mapStatetoprop but it does not update the UI

```
    const propTypes = {
    teamPlayers : PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    matchesData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    isfetchingTeamPlayer: PropTypes.bool.isRequired

};


   class CreateTeam extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedPlayerIDs : [],
        count:0,
        isforward:false,
        show:false,
        message:''
    }
    this.toggleChecked = this.toggleChecked.bind(this);
    this.forwardRoute = this.forwardRoute.bind(this);
    this.previousRoute = this.previousRoute.bind(this);


}

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.createTeam(this.props.matchID);
}


renderPlayerCard() {    console.log(this.props.teamPlayers)
       let count = 0;
        return this.props.teamPlayers.map((player) => {
            if(player.isChecked){
                count+=1;
            }

            let mtype = '';


            return (
                <PlayerCard
                    key={player.id}
                    player={player}
                    mtype={mtype}
                    count={count}
                    selectedPlayerIDs={this.state.selectedPlayerIDs}
                    triggerChanges={this.toggleChecked}
                />

            );

        })
    }

    render () {



    if(!this.props.isfetchingTeamPlayer && !this.props.isPlayersFetching ){
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
        }
        console.log("selected5Players"+this.props.selected5Players)
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="container-grey">
                        <div className="timer2">
                            <table className="timer-table2">

                               {
                                   this.props.matchesData.end_time ?
                                       <Counter
                                           endDate={this.props.matchesData.end_time}
                                       /> : null
                               }

                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <table className="team-table2">
                                <tr className="match-team">
                                    <td className='team-logo-box'>
                                        <div className="white-box">
                                            {
                                                this.props.matchesData.hasOwnProperty('teams') ?

                                                    <img className="team-logo2" alt="Team1"
                                                         src={this.props.matchesData.teams.home_team.flag_path}/>
                                                    :null
                                            }
                                            </div>
                                    </td>

                                    <td className="team-name2 left">{this.props.matchesData.teams.away_team.short_name}</td>
                                    <td><img className="versus2" alt="versus" src={vs}/></td>
                                    <td className="team-name2 right">{this.props.matchesData.teams.away_team.short_name} </td>
                                    <td className='team-logo-box'>
                                        <div className="white-box">
                                            <img className="team-logo2" alt="Team2"
                                                 src={this.props.matchesData.teams.away_team.flag_path}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                             </table>

                    </div>


                    <div className="player-list">
                        <table className="timer-table2">
                            <tbody>
                                {this.renderPlayerCard()}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="foot-container">



                </div>

            </div>




        );
    }
}
CreateTeam.propTypes = propTypes;

const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
    // I am getting updated state here but doesn't call the render function//
    console.log("state Changes but does not call the render function of this component")

    return {
        matchID: ownProps.params.teamID,
        selected5Players: state.matchesTeam.selected5Players,
        teamPlayers: selectedCheckedplayers(state),
        matchesData: state.matchesTeam.matchesData,
        isfetchingTeamPlayer: state.matchesTeam.isfetchingTeamPlayer,
        isPlayersFetching: state.matchesTeam.isPlayersFetching
    }
};
```

> Below the code of child component where i dispatch the action

here i dispatching the action on every checkbox (handleChange() function ) see below

```
const propTypes = {
    player: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

class PlayerCard extends React.Component {


    handleChange(evt,id,isSelected) {   
          this.props.togglePlayersChecked({"player":this.props.player,"status":!isSelected})
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <tr>
                <td className="batsmen-pic">
                    <img alt='batsmen' className='batsmen-picture' src={this.props.player.photo_url} />
                </td>
                <td className="batsmen-details">
                    <div className="batsmen-name left">
                        <div className="first-name">{this.props.player.name}</div>
                    </div>


                </td>
                <td className="batsmen-checkbox-holder">
                    <div>
                        <input className="batsmen-checkbox"
                               type="checkbox"
                               onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, this.props.player,this.props.player.isChecked)}
                               value={this.props.player.id}
                               checked={this.props.player.isChecked }

                        />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }


}
PlayerCard.propTypes = propTypes;

const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => ({
    selected5Players: state.matchesTeam.selected5Players,

});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
    togglePlayersChecked
}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PlayerCard);
```

> below the code of Reducer function of this action

```
const createTeamReducer = createReducer({
    [createTeam]: (state) => ({
        ...state,
        isfetchingTeamPlayer: true,
    }),


    [createTeam.error]: (state, error) => ({
        ...state,
        teamPlayerError: error,
        isfetchingTeamPlayer: false,
        isPlayersFetching:true
    }),

    [createTeam.success]: (state, payload) => {
        const teamPlayers = normalize(payload.players);
        const matchesData = {...payload.match_data};
        const isSaved = true;

        return { ...state,matchesData, teamPlayers, isSaved ,isRefreshingTeamPlayer: false };
    },

    [togglePlayersChecked]: (state, payload) => {   console.log(payload)
        let teamPlayers = state.teamPlayers;
        const isSaved = false;
        let selected5Players = state.selected5Players;
        if (payload.status) {
            if (selected5Players.length >= 5){
                //alert("You can't select more then five");
                return { ...state, teamPlayers,selected5Players};
            }else {
                const index = teamPlayers.findIndex((player) => player.id === payload.player.id);
                teamPlayers[index].isChecked = true;
                selected5Players.push(payload.player);
            }
        } else {
            const index = teamPlayers.findIndex((player) => player.id === payload.player.id);
            console.log(index);
            var c = selected5Players.findIndex((val) => val.id === payload.player.id);
            selected5Players.splice(c,1);
            console.log(selected5Players)
            teamPlayers[index].isChecked = false;


        }

        return { ...state, teamPlayers,selected5Players,isSaved};

    },
    [get5player]:(state,payload) => {

        const selectedTeamplayer = [...state.selected5Players];
        const istwoSelected = true;
        console.log(selectedTeamplayer);
        return { ...state, selectedTeamplayer,istwoSelected};

    },

    [get5Batsmen2BestBatsmen]:(state,payload) => {
        let select5BatsmenAnd2BestBatsmen = [];
        return { ...state, select5BatsmenAnd2BestBatsmen};

    },

    [deleteTeam]:(state,payload) => {
        let selected5Players = [];
        let select2batsmen = [];
        let teamPlayers = [];
        const isSaved = true;
        const select5BatsmenAnd2BestBatsmen = [];
        return {...state, select2batsmen, selected5Players,teamPlayers,isSaved,select5BatsmenAnd2BestBatsmen};
    }


}, initialState);

export default createTeamReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be mutating the state inside reducer instead of returning new state. Hence the changes are not detected.